# Future metod: How to avoid writing same query multiple times

Tags: apex, soql, webservices, callout, map

Below is my class where I have to use same list results 4 times. So I moved it to a class. But since the methods postCases_User and postCases_Queue are future methods, I believe I can use only primitive datatype and not an sObject. So is there a way to avoid writing same query 4 times ?

```
public with sharing class caseTriggerPostHandler {  

    public class fetchRecords{
        public list<case> caseRecord = new list<case>([Select Id, status, owner.type, owner.profile.name From Case Where ID IN :trigger.new]);
    }

    public void caseInsert(list<case> caseList){
        fetchRecords f = new fetchRecords();
        caseList = f.caseRecord;
        if(caseList.size() > 0){
            for(case c : caseList){
                if(c.Status != 'closed'){
                    if(c.owner.type == 'User'){
                        postCases_User(c);
                    } else if (c.owner.type == 'Queue'){
                        postCases_Queue(c);
                    }
                }           
            }
        }
    }

    public void caseUpdate(list<case> caseList, map<id, case> oldMap, map<id, case> newMap){
        fetchRecords f = new fetchRecords();
        caseList = f.caseRecord;
        if(caseList.size() >0){
            for(case c : caseList){     
                if(c.Status != 'closed'){                
                    if(c.owner.type == 'User' && oldMap.get(c.id).status != newMap.get(c.id).status ){
                            postCases_User(c);
                    } else if (c.owner.type == 'Queue' && oldMap.get(c.id).status != newMap.get(c.id).status ){
                            postCases_Queue(c);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }      
    }


    @future(callout = true)
    public static void postCases_User (case c){
        system.debug(c.owner.type);
    }

    @future (callout = true)
    public static void postCases_Queue (case c){
       system.debug('FromQueue'+c.owner.type);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to pass sObjects into a future method would be to serialize the List into a JSON string and then deserialize it in the future method, as well as using collections to only have to call the future method once:

```
Case[] userCase = New Case[]{};
Case[] queueCase = New Case[]{};

if(c.owner.type == 'User'){
                        userCase.add(c);
                    } else if (c.owner.type == 'Queue'){
                        queueCase.add(c);
                    }

postCases_User(JSON.serialize(userCase);
postCases_Queue(JSON.serialize(queueCase);
```

**future**

```
 @future(callout = true)
    public static void postCases_User (String cList){
      Case[] userCases = (Case[])JSON.deserialize(cList,List<Case>.class);  
      for(Case c : userCases)
       system.debug(c.owner.type);
    }

    @future (callout = true)
    public static void postCases_Queue (String cList){
       Case[] queueCases = (Case[])JSON.deserialize(cList,List<Case>.class);  
      for(Case c : queueCases)
       system.debug(c.owner.type);
    }
```

You can refine further as needed...

Comment: n.b. if the Case changed between the time of the future call and the time when the future executed, the callouts are done with invalid data (serialized sobject). This may or may not be an issue in your application

Comment: crop1645.. Issue you mentioned, I believe is definitely an issue in my application because agents might change the field attributes on case, save and repeat while they are still on call. So is it best practice to have a separate query in future methods ?

Comment: It could be an issue, but if they update the case, another future method will be called and the new data sent.....BUT since the order of execution is not guaranteed you run the risk of the latest update being sent before the older one. Either way you have to account for it...If you query, you will not get the previous update, just the latest one so it all depends on what you are trying to do and how the endpoint works. Unless you implement some sort of batching method or flow control each update trigger a callout so regardless of query or serialization you run into the same issues

Comment: All things to think about. - Thanks for pointing that out @crop1645 as it was a big point I neglected to mention. Oh, also, keep in mind the limits on number future invocations per 24 hours, although large, could it be possible you would hit them?

Comment: and another note -- a) @Eric 's answer correctly bulkifies the trigger b) which means you (@pmvsdt) need to be sure your trigger works as expected when bulk updating (Data Loader-type) operations are done against the Case as you mentioned the use case is for call center agents.